# C program opens terminal in VSCode of MacBook Air M1

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, apple-silicon, visual-studio-code

I am running this code in VSCode on my MacBook Air M1

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    double pi=(double)355/113,r;

    printf("Enter the radius of the circle\n");
    scanf("%lf",&r);

    printf("The area of the circle is: %f\n",pi*r*r);
    return 0;
}
```

On clicking run c/c++ button, it opens an instance of the terminal instead of the VSCode integrated terminal.[image: See image here]

The debug console loads .dylib files

This is my launch.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: clang build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang build active file"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

this is my tasks.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

How do I make it run in the integrated console?
Also, this problem is unique to C, Python & Java run in the VSCode integrated terminal without issues (and without CodeRunner)

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure VSCode compiles code? The other languages are interpreted and have repl…

Comment: I don't use VSCode but in you config you do have `"externalConsole": true,` which would suggest that the VSCode console is not used.

Comment: @mmmmmm if i have it as false, nothing happens. Debug console just loads the .dylib files and terminal displays 'terminal will be reused by tasks'

Comment: @bmike CodeRunner does compile it and show it in integrated terminal. Running the file by clicking Run C/C++ file runs as i have described. The compiled code file is also generated.

Comment: Very cool integration. Thanks for filling in a gap in my knowledge there. I wonder if the code `settings.json` file [could have a value for the integrated terminal that give it a zsh shell or other bump](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73256795/475228) to avoid calling any external editor (or perhaps to have the "external editor" be "code"??